# Django: While Button Pressed

Tags: django

I am currently working on a control for a camera (visca-over-ip) having 4 buttons that control in which direction the camera should turn. Currently I am in the testing phase and now need these 4 Buttons to set a variable in django to TRUE if the Button is held. If it was let go something else should happen.

It should be something Like:

index.html:

<button>Left</button>

camera.py

button_pressed = (Code that checks if button is held down)

def button_hold():

```
     while button_pressed == True:

             (do something)
```